# extract string from another using grep

Tags: shell, grep

I'am new in shell development. And I want to extract  `cfgxxxx` from the uci command result using grep utility

```
#uci show -X fire |grep "fire\.[^.]\+\.instance

fire.cfg1a3837.instance=1
fire.cfg1c3837.instance=2
fire.cfg243837.instance=3
fire.cfg263837.instance=4
fire.cfg283837.instance=5
fire.cfg2a3837.instance=6
fire.cfg2c3837.instance=7
fire.cfg2e3837.instance=8
fire.cfg303837.instance=9
fire.cfg323837.instance=10
```

but the following command doesn't extract the exact value

```
#uci show -X fire |grep "fire\.[^.]\+\.instance=1" | cut -d. -f2
cfg1a3837  --> instance=1
cfg323837  --> instance=10
```

how extract only the instance number 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uci show -X fire |grep "fire\.[^.]\+\.instance=1$" | cut -d. -f2
```

You need to add a `$` else `=1` and `=10` will be treated same.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use awk and reduce 2 commands into one:

```
uci show -X fire | awk -F '\\.' '$1=="fire"{print $2}'
cfg1a3837
cfg1c3837
cfg243837
cfg263837
cfg283837
cfg2a3837
cfg2c3837
cfg2e3837
cfg303837
cfg323837
```

You can also use this `grep -oP`:

```
uci show -X fire | grep -oP "fire\.\K[^.]+(?=\.instance)"
```